# Login screen shows "User" instead of my actual account name

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04, created my admin account as well as 2 non-admin accounts. Now, at the login page, it displays my account name as "User" instead of my actual account name. Everything else is normal (the 2 other account names are displayed correctly). When I log in and open a terminal, the prompt is jfk@ubuntu and my home is /home/jfk as expected. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go To **System Settings** and then **User Accounts** Then Select Your  **User-name** That Should Be **JFK** And Change Your **Name** Their I Hope This Helps.

Comment: Just beat me to it... =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your 'Full Name' - look in users and groups:
[image: User Properties]